# How can you trace execution of an embedded system emulted in QEMU?

Tags: gdb, trace, qemu, openwrt

I've built  OpenWrt for x86 and I'm using QEMU to run it virtually.I'm trying to debug this system in real time.  I need to see things like network traffic flowing etc.

I can attach gdb remotely and execute (mostly) step by step with break points. I really want trace points though. I don't want to pause execution and loose network flow. When I tried setting trace points using tstart, I see the message "Target does not support this command". I did a bit of reading of the gdb documentation and from what I can tell the gdb stub that runs to intercept normal execution in QEMU does not support trace points.

From here I started looking at other tools and ran across PANDA (https://github.com/panda-re/panda). As I understand PANDA will capture a complete system trace in a log and allow for replay. I think this tool is supposed to do what I need, but I cannot seem to replay the results. I see the logs, I just can't replay them.

Now, I'm a bit stuck on what other tools/options I might have to actually trace a running embedded system. Are there any good tools you can recommend? Or perhaps another method I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the system calls and signals use strace.
Strace can also be used with running process and it can put the output in a log file if required.

Comment: I'll take a look at strace. Is it a package in OpenWrt already? I suppose I could make it so if it is not.

Comment: Yes, do make menuconfig and search for strace.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenWrt it is possible to build with ftrace. Ftrace has much of the functionality I required but not all.

To build with ftrace, the option for ftrace must be selected in the build menu. Additionally there are a variety of tracer options that must also be enabled.

The trace-cmd (ftrace) is located in menuconfig/Development

Tracing support is under menuconfig/Global build settings/Compile the kernel with tracing support and includes: Trace system calls, Trace process context switches and events, and Function tracer (Function graph tracer, Enable/disable function tracing dynamically, and Function profiler)

I'm also planning to build a custom GDB stub to do this a little bit better as I also want to see the data passed to the functions not just the function calls.